# Spin-Igor unable to query Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, spinnaker

I'm having trouble getting spin-igor to view jobs from our Jenkins.

Spinnaker 1.17.6

We use a custom CA on the jenkins.  I've added a PKS trust store to the HAL config using:

`hal config webhook trust edit --trustStore /tmp/our-int.jks --trustStorePassword`

then added the truststore info to the jenkins master section of the hal config manually:

```
   trustStore: /tmp/our-int.jks
   trustStoreType: jks
   trustStorePassword: thepassword
```

the logs simply show a 500 trying to read, before adding the trust store info i was getting PKI errors, so it seems the trust store is working.

I verified that I can wget files from the the spin-igor container over DNS allowing self-signed certs, the /api/xml is denied however (expected as there is no authentication happening yet):

```
bash-4.4$ wget --no-check-certificate https://jenkins.jx.internal.dns/login
Connecting to jenkins.jx.internal.dns (10.11.33.181:443)
login                100% |*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************|  1485  0:00:00 ETA
bash-4.4$ wget --no-check-certificate https://jenkins.jx.internal.dns/api/xml
Connecting to jenkins.jx.internal.dns (10.11.33.181:443)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

The username/password in the config is correct.. I can copy them out of the config and connect. What else I can be looking at for connecting? Here's the jenkins section of config:

```
devops@a21de9934279:/home/spinnaker/.hal$ sudo cat /home/spinnaker/.hal/config | yq .deploymentConfigurations[].ci
{
  "jenkins": {
    "enabled": true,
    "masters": [
      {
        "name": "jenkins",
        "permissions": {},
        "address": "https://jenkins.jx.internal.dns/",
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "XXXXXXX",
        "csrf": true,
        "trustStore": "/tmp/out-int.jks",
        "trustStoreType": "jks",
        "trustStorePassword": "password"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here are the most relevant logs I can find on the spin-igor container:

```
2020-01-20 19:02:30.680 ERROR 1 --- [RxIoScheduler-3] c.n.s.igor.jenkins.JenkinsBuildMonitor   : Failed to update monitor items for monitor=JenkinsBuildMonitor:partition=jenkins
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: jenkins-covr-jenkins-getProjects failed and no fallback available.
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:822) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:807) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
```

and

```
Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: 500 Server Error
        at retrofit.RetrofitError.httpError(RetrofitError.java:40) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:388) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
```

If I log in via web browser to jenkins and hit `/api/xml` I do get data, so I'm a bit perplexed as what else to try.

I did also follow the instructions to enable CSRF on Jenkins.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I found a solution (workaround) posted by another user: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/892#issuecomment-320336522
good 'ol #Jankins

tl/dr go to security settings and switch auth mode from "servlet container" to "jenkins own DB" and then add a user manually.. apparently the k8s auth is broken somehow